# How to change string into JSON format structure using PHP?

Tags: php

I have these code to pull data from two different database.

And I need to eliminate the same row by 'staffid'.

So far I can eliminate the duplicate. But the output is not what I want it to be.

**index.php**

```
<?php

    // PART A
    require 'conn.php';
    $query = "SELECT STAFFID FROM TABLE";
    $result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($result);
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result,OCI_NUM)){
        $arr[] = $row[0]; 
    } 


    // PART B
    $url="http://localhost/fetch_data.php";  
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    $result=curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 


    foreach(json_decode($result) as $result2)
    {
        if(!in_array($result2[0],$arr))
        {
            $total = "".$result2[0].",".$result2[1].",".$result2[2]."<br/>"; 
            echo json_encode($total);
        }       
    }
?>
```

The output for far for the above code as below

```
"A001","BILLY","email1@mail.com"
"A002","JOHN","email2@mail.com"
"A003","SALLY","email3@mail.com"
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
    include_once('conn.php');

    $arr        = array();
    $query      = "SELECT * FROM TABLE "; 
    $stmt       = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query);
    $result     = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    $row        = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

    $array  = array();
    while( $self = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt)) { 

        $array2 = array();
        $array2[]= $self['ID'];  
        $array2[]= $self['NAME'];  
        $array2[]= $self['EMAIL'];  

        $array[] =  $array2;
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

My goal is to change it into JSON as below. I'm missing the bracket and the coma.

```
[
    ["A001","BILLY","email1@mail.com"],
    ["A002","JOHN","email2@mail.com"],
    ["A003","SALLY","email3@mail.com"]
]
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I want the output to be like [
    ["A001","BILLY","email1@mail.com"],
    ["A002","JOHN","email2@mail.com"],
    ["A003","SALLY","email3@mail.com"]
]

Comment: And you need that output from `index.php` right?

Comment: @PeterM . Yup, I need to echo the output in index.php only. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
foreach(json_decode($result) as $result2)
{
    if(!in_array($result2[0],$arr))
    {
        $total = "".$result2[0].",".$result2[1].",".$result2[2]."<br/>"; 
        echo json_encode($total);
    }       
}
```

into

```
foreach(json_decode($result) as $result2)
{
    if(!in_array($result2[0],$arr))
    {
        $total[] = $result2; 
    }       
}
echo json_encode($total);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I add bracket for each row of data ?

Comment: @Rozaimi this should do the trick, json_encode does all the magic for your, no need to add the brackets `[]` on your own. Also don't add `<br/>` in there, your JSON will be invalid.